# Problem compiling Qt example from OS X terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt

I'm currently learning Qt by working through examples in the ebook "C+ GUI Programming with Qt 4, Second Edition".

The first example is a "Hello World" application. Following the steps in the example I've been able to create the following files:

- hello.cpp, by typing out the provided code.
- hello.pro, by using OS X Terminal command "qmake -project".
- hello.xcodeproj and info.plist by using command "qmake hello.pro"

However, I am unable to create "hello.app"

The command "make" yields:

```
"make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."
```

The command "make hello" yields:

```
g++     hello.cpp   -o hello
hello.cpp:1:24: error: QApplication: No such file or directory
hello.cpp:2:18: error: QLabel: No such file or directory
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hello.cpp:6: error: ‘QApplication’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:6: error: expected `;' before ‘app’
hello.cpp:7: error: ‘QLabel’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:7: error: ‘label’ was not declared in this scope
hello.cpp:7: error: expected type-specifier before ‘QLabel’
hello.cpp:7: error: expected `;' before ‘QLabel’
hello.cpp:9: error: ‘app’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

While I can't create "hello.app" from the terminal with these two commands, I can create it by simply opening Xcode and pressing the button "Build and Go".

Can someone tell me why in the world these two commands don't work? And how I can make the "hello.app" from the terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I see that `qmake` has generated an `*.xcodeproj`-file for you. Try running `xcodebuild` instead of `make` :)

Comment: Thanks Magnus Hoff! xcodebuild did the trick! That's what I needed to know!

Comment: Also it's worth to mention, that if you want to generate makefiles instead of xcodeproj, you may call qmake -spec macx-g++

Comment: @Kamil Klimek: Thanks. I was looking for that, but somehow never found out :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't include the directories from the Qt SDK in your makefile paths. Did you also remember to run QMake?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you download and install [Qt SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads). Then familiar yourself with [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/), the IDE for Qt. It's much easier that way since all the frameworks and docs are installed and configured for you.